# MySQL SUM Column based on unique values in another

Tags: mysql, join

I have a stock table which lists parts, warehouse locations, and quantity in that location. There are currently duplicate entries for the same location and I would like to merge these together.

For example

```
ID | Part_Number | Location | Quantity
1  | 12345       | A1       | 100
2  | 12345       | A1       | 50
3  | 12345       | A2       | 300
4  | 67890       | A1       | 200
```

I want to get it so the two 12345 entries in location A1 are changed to a single showing 150 stock.

I am trying to achieve this using JOINS but I'm struggling as I don't completely understand how they work. So far I have only managed to sum the entire table.

Comment: It may be worth reading https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions-and-modifiers.html

Answer (score 1):

use group by `part_number, location`

```
select part_number, location, sum(quantity) as stkquantity
from tablename
group by part_number, location
```